# webpack config cannot use ES6 import for relative path

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, yarnpkg, es6-modules

I have converted my Webpack configuration files from CommonJS to ES6 Modules to [cjs-to-es6](https://github.com/nolanlawson/cjs-to-es6). Some of the ES6 import statements such as this works:

```
import config from '../config'
```

Whilst this line does not work

```
import utils from './utils'
```

Resulting in this error

```
$ babel-node ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js
/my/directory/build/vue-loader.conf.js:34
  loaders: _utils2.default.cssLoaders({
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'cssLoaders' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/my/directory/build/vue-loader.conf.js:19:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
    at loader (/Users/hanxue/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/hanxue/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/my/directory/build/webpack.base.conf.js:5:1)
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
```

### Workaround

Changing

```
import utils from './utils'
```

to

```
const utils = require('./utils')
```

will eliminate the error message.

### Background

webpack: 4.0.1
node: v9.8.0
yarn: 1.5.1

#### Directory structure

```
$ ls -a config/
.       .babelrc    index.js    test.env.js
..      dev.env.js  prod.env.js
$ ls -a build/
.           check-versions.js   webpack.base.conf.js
..          logo.png        webpack.dev.conf.js
.babelrc        utils.js        webpack.prod.conf.js
build.js        vue-loader.conf.js  webpack.temp.js
```

Content of `build/.babelrc` and `config/.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Relevant `package.json` content

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "babel-node ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "unit": "jest --config test/unit/jest.conf.js --coverage",
    "e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
    "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit/specs test/e2e/specs",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
```

### Question

How can I make `import utils from './utils'` work correctly?

Comment: Without knowing how `utils` exports `cssLoaders` this isn't answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `import utils from './utils'` to `import * as utils from './utils'`.

- `import something from 'module'` imports the `default` `export` as `something`
- `import * as something from 'module'` imports everything as `something`

It only works if `utils.js` is an ES6 module (which I assume), if it's a CommonJS module (`module.exports`) then both should work.

At runtime the Babel CommonJS plugin will check if the module is ES6 or CommonJS (using `__esModule`) and :

- with `import default from module` :

  - if it's a CommonJS module : return `module.exports`
  - if it's an ES6 module : return `export default` (this is why it doesn't work for you)
- with `import * as all from module` :

  - if it's a CommonJS module : return `module.exports`
  - if it's an ES6 module : return all named exports in an object